# Inserting record to MS Access with PHP

Tags: php, sql, ms-access, insert, odbc

so straight to the problem. I'm working with php on a local DSN MS Access database. But the insert function doesnt work, no record added after running the page.

Here are the code.

```
<?php

$conn=odbc_connect('rewardscard','','');
if (!$conn) {
    exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);
}

$username=$_POST['username']; 
$birthday=$_POST['birthday'];
$gender=$_POST['gender'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

$sql="SELECT * FROM UserInfo";
$user=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
if (!$user) {
    exit("Error in SQL");
}

$newid=0;
while (odbc_fetch_row($user)) {
    $lastuser=odbc_result($user, "UserID");
    if ($newid < preg_match_all('!\d+!', $lastuser, $lastuserint)) {
        $newid=$lastuserint+1;
    }
}

$userid="$newid".'U';

$comid=001;
$balance=0;

$sql1="INSERT INTO UserInfo (UserID, UserName, Password, Birthday, Gender, Phone, Address, CompanyID, Balance) VALUES ('$userid','$username','$password','$birthday','$gender','$phone','$address','$comid','$balance')";
$result=odbc_exec($conn,$sql1);
echo $result;

session_start();
$_SESSION['username']=$username;
/*--    header("Location: home.php");--*/

?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, no error message, but on the database interface, no record was inserted.

Comment: Have you tried adding `ini_set('display_errors', 'on');` to the beginning of your script?

Comment: No wonder there's no error message: you are not using `odbc_errormsg()` at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure but the SQL command seems messy. Try something like this:

```
`INSERT INTO UserInfo (userid, username, ...) VALUES ('$userid','$username','$birthday','$gender','$phone','$address','$password','$comid','$balance')`
```

Use your correct field names, of course.

Comment: checked it again, and still not working. any other reason that could cause this problem? or any troubleshoot method suggested?
thanks!

Comment: Could you please `echo $result;` after the SQL insert command? What is the value?

Comment: Just did and realised the problem was with
    $userid="$newid".'U';
So what i was trying to was read the last user id"e.g. 0003U", get rid of the "U", and make the number +1(which i forgot and have added already), and then make it 4U and add to the record.
sorry for the messy description, its my first time working with php.

Comment: Ok! No problem. But I suggest you to use an autoincrement for the userid. So you have not to worry about generating the userid by yourself. Good luck with your efforts in PHP.